# UPPAAL Verifier

Tags: model, verification, uppaal

I have a model in the UPPAAL software, and try to verify whether items[2] == 3 in every case. I've tried with that:
A<>(items[0] == 0 and items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rRuB.png) == 0 and items[2] == 3)

I made a "closing" state (for every template) and the model goes there whether items[2] == 3. From that state there is no outwards. If i read the documentation correctly A<> exactly should find this state and there check whether items[2] == 3.

Do you know what im doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rRuB.png)

I checked and it is the only deadlock/livelock

Thanks in forward!

Comment: what do you mean by "every case"? every path? every state?

Comment: i mean at the end of every path

Answer (score 0):

`A<>` property may become false if there is a deadlock or an infinite trace avoiding the state property.

Try enabling the `Diagnostic trace` in `Options`, then check the property again and inspect the trace in the simulator. Beware of deadlocks, infinite delays and infinite loops (the last steps appear highlighted in red).